Duplicar registros de dos tablas que tienen relacion
el contexto es el siguiente:
Tengo 2 tablas una de venta y otra de detalle_venta que están relacionadas por el atributo venta_id y pues me preguntaba si es posible duplicar los registros de ambas tablas relacionadas

Tabla1: venta




venta_id
fecha
invoice
total




1ef033ea
24-04-21
551
280.00


a3a2f7f7
24-04-21
551
50.00


5765ff15
24-04-21
551
120.00




Tabla2: detalle_venta




id
venta_id
producto_id
cantidad




1010
1ef033ea
RSD15
2


1011
1ef033ea
AZI11
10


1011
a3a2f7f7
TMJ02
1


1011
5765ff15
JCF88
4



Intente hacer esto
INSERT INTO venta(venta_id, fecha, invoice, total)
SELECT 
    uuid(), -- Nuevo UUID
    fecha,
    total
FROM 
    venta
WHERE fecha like '2024-04%'

INSERT INTO detalle_venta(id, venta_id, producto_id, cantidad)
SELECT
    id,
    uuid(), -- Nuevo UUID
    fecha,
    total
FROM 
    venta
WHERE fecha like '2024-04%'

con estas sentencias SQL en la tabla detalle_venta, el atributo uuid nuevo no esta relacionado con la tabla venta y el id no se incrementa, entiendo que puede ser un proceso ETL pero que metodos puedo usar para el fin que busco

Por cierto "fecho" no es VARCHAR, sino DATE, ¿verdad? Entonces, no uses una función para cadenas de caracteres (LIKE), sino funcionas u operadores de DATE. Por ejemplo WHERE fecha >= DATE '2024-04-01' AND fecha < DATE '2024-05-01'.

Para poder insertar exitosamente los encabezados y detalles, necesitas mantener información que te permita relacionar cada ID que tomas de la tabla de encabezado con el ID que le corresponde al nuevo registro insertado en dicha tabla.
De esta manera, puedes ubicar los detalles que corresponden a dicho registro para insertar los que corresponden al nuevo encabezado también.
Una manera sencilla de mantener dicha información es en una tabla temporal, por ejemplo:
create temporary table rel_vta 
select venta_id, uuid() as nuevoid 
  from venta 
 where fecha like '2024-04%';

Va a dejar cada ID existente en la tabla venta junto a un nuevo ID para todos los registros que coinciden con el criterio del where.
A partir de allí, haciendo join a esta tabla, podemos tener acceso a los datos de las tablas de encabezado y detalle, junto al nuevo ID que le corresponde a cada registro.
Insertar entonces, sería algo como:
insert into venta (venta_id, fecha, invoice, total)
select rel_vta.nuevoid, venta.fecha, venta.invoice, venta.total
  from venta
       inner join rel_vta on rel_vta.venta_id = venta.venta_id;
       
insert into detalle_venta(id, venta_id, producto_id, cantidad)
select uuid(), rel_vta.nuevoid
       , detalle_venta.producto_id, detalle_venta.cantidad
  from detalle_venta
       inner join rel_vta on rel_vta.venta_id = detalle_venta.venta_id

